# How to find the length of each words in an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working on this matlab code which is to read the contents from a text document and store the words into an array and to find the length of each word.The following is my code:

```
file1=fopen('doc1.txt','r');
%file 1 is now open
%read data from file 1
text1=fileread('doc1.txt');
%now text1 has the content of doc1 as a string.Next split the sentences
%into words.For that we are calling the split function
temp1=strsplit(text1,' ');
[r,c]=size(temp1);
disp('The total number of distinct words in the document are ')
c
disp('And those words are :')
for i=1:c
   k= temp1(i)
    length(k)
end
```

Here no matter what the length of each word is, length(k) always display 1. Can somebody help me with a solution to this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`temp1` is a `cell` array. You should extract the individual strings using brace indexing, like so

```
words = 'foo bar1 baz23';
temp1 = strsplit(words, ' ');
for i = 1:numel(temp1)
    k = temp1{i}
    length(k)
end
```

Comment: or `cellfun(@length, temp1)` for short

Comment: or `cellfun('length', temp1)` for short & fast ;)

Comment: I have one more doubt.I could retrieve the contents of each cell and was able to do some processing(which is converting each word into a keyword.ie, happiness->happi,ended->end etc.)I could perform the processing to all the words except for the last word. But then again when I added a space between the last word,which is "happiness" and the period, it worked.Can you please explain why that happened and a possible way out because I think in a real life project with user interaction,I don't think that the user can be insisted on maintaining a whitespace between the final word and the period.

Comment: @sebastian do you have a link that explains why using a string is faster than a function handle?

Comment: @Geethu It happens because you're only splitting on spaces and not on punctuation marks. I think you could probably get away with removing all the punctuation marks you don't want to count as a preprocessing step. So something like `words2 = words(words ~= '.')`...

Comment: @dan nope - but all of the "string"-cellfun versions (from the "backwards compatibility" section in the docs) are significantly faster than their function-handle counterpart. Most certainly because they skip the function-handle-calling overhead and call the internal `length`, `isempty` etc. functions more directly.

Comment: You were splitting on `' '` - so when there is no space, you don't get the split you are expecting. Perhaps you should change the way you split the text.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, you should accept the answer, so the person who helped you get credit for it. @Geethu